# Coefficients when rewriting the Hook-Content polynomials in terms of binomial polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, schur-functors

Let $\lambda$ be a partition, $S_\lambda$ the Schur functor attached to $\lambda$, and let $p_\lambda(t)$ be the polynomial determined by the condition that $\dim S_\lambda(k^n) = p_\lambda(n)$ for non-negative integers $n$. Equivalently $p_\lambda(n)$ is the dimension of the $\lambda$-irrep of $\mathrm{GL}(n)$, or the number of semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ with entries in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

This polynomial $p_{\lambda}(t)$ is also called the [Hook-Content polynomial](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hook-content+formula) and has the explicit formula
$$ p_{\lambda}(t) = \prod_{u \in \lambda} \frac{t+c(u)}{h(u)},$$
where $h(u)$ is the hook-length and $c(u)$ the content of the box $u$. It is not difficult to see, from any of the definitions of $p_{\lambda}(t)$ we have discussed, that this polynomial is integer-valued in the sense that if $n$ is an integer then $p_\lambda(n)$ is an integer (here's an [elementary proof](https://www.isibang.ac.in/%7Esury/integ.pdf) but it also follows easily from Corollary 2 [here](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Cahen-Chabert.pdf)).

Pòlya showed that the ring of integer valued polynomials has a basis given by the polynomials in $n$ of the form $\binom{n}{k}$. In particular we have that there are some integers $C(k,\lambda)$ such that:
$$p_\lambda(n) = \sum_{k} C(k,\lambda) \binom{n}{k}$$

Do these $C(k,\lambda)$ have a name?

(The motivation is that these numbers appear in Section 8.5 of [our preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.15392.pdf) with Harman and Snowden. They seem classical enough that surely they're already studied, but I can't seem to find them discussed anywhere else.)

Comment: Unrelated, but: That's a nice algebra you have defined there! Any plans for an elementary  treatise for those not familiar with functional analysis? I'd like to see the direct derivations mentioned in Section 9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These coefficients can be understood using the theory of $(P,\omega)$-partitions, as discussed for example in Section 3.15 of Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics," Volume 1, 2nd edition.

But even without that general theory, it's easy to see directly that $C(\lambda,k)$ is the number of SSYT of shape $\lambda$ with entries in $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that all of $1,\ldots,k$ appear as entries (a “surjective” tableau, one might say). The reason is this: we make an SSYT of shape $\lambda$ with entries in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ by first choosing the number $k$ of different entries, then choosing a surjective tableau, then picking the $k$ of the $n$ entries that appear. Hence if $B(\lambda,k)$ is the number of surjective tableaux with image $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ we have $p_{\lambda}(n) = \sum_{k}B(\lambda,k)\binom{n}{k}$ for all $n$. So indeed $B(\lambda,k)=C(\lambda,k)$. This same reasoning (but at the generality of $(P,\omega)$-partitions) appears on pg. 303 of Stanley.

Since these $C(\lambda,k)$ have this simple interpretation, I would guess they have no special name.

Comment: Thanks, that's very nice!